# Riding or driving?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Said to a person in a wheelchair:

You shouldn't be riding/driving that thing drunk.

- Are both natural?
- Does any of them require an "in" after it in the sentence?

Comment: Is the wheelchair motorized?  "Driving" is really only used for a motorized vehicle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you ride a car?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157444/do-you-ride-a-car) Also [Why the word "ride" is used in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187758/why-the-word-ride-is-used-in-this-sentence) and [Driving vs. Riding](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250495/driving-vs-riding), among others.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's define some terms.**

*[Drive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive):*

> to operate the mechanism and controls and direct the course of (a vehicle)

Relating to the previous definition, we must also define [*vehicle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vehicle):

> a means of carrying or transporting something

[*Ride*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ride):

> to travel in or on a conveyance

Let's define [*conveyance*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conveyance), too:

> a means of transport

Is a wheelchair a vehicle? Yes. Is this person in a wheelchair operating its controls and directing its course? Presumably in this case. Is this person travelling in or on some means of transport? Yes, he travels in a wheelchair.

**Therefore, the person is by definition driving and riding the wheelchair.**

---

That being said, @CanadianYankee makes a good point in the comments:

> "Driving" is really only used for a motorized vehicle.

It is true that one normally *drives* a car or motorcycle, and it's also true that one normally *rides* a bike (*on* being left implicit) but *rides in* (*in* being explicitly stated) a car unless they are on the roof and clinging to the bike rack for dear life. Considering the definition of *in* is conventionally stretched to permit a person to sit *in* an armchair rather than *on* it, I would say:

> You shouldn't be riding *in* that thing drunk.

If you choose to use *drive*, I would say the preposition is optional.

**TL;DR:** Both are okay, but perhaps you should consider using *using* or *operating* for a more natural phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Riding implies more of a passive interaction with a vehicle, and driving is a direct action one takes with a vehicle. (This is part of the reason why the slogan "don't drink and drive" is effective, apart from the allileration)

In this case, to ride something while drunk is not necessarily a big deal, but directly operating a vehicle would be considered dangerous.

For a person in a wheelchair, it would be more appropriate to say "drive" but it might still seem strange because a wheelchair is more so "operated" than "driven".

If I was pushing someone in a wheelchair while they were drunk, the situation would be pretty safe and the person would be "riding".